# Get Jenkins artifacts URl from REST api

Tags: rest, jenkins

Is there any way to get artifacts download url from jenkins **REST API**. I am using `artifact deployer` and artifacts can be download from

```
http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/buildId/deployedartifact/downloads/artifacts.{id}
```

Is it possible to get the url infomation from REST api??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins REST API - using tree to reference specific item in JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236710/jenkins-rest-api-using-tree-to-reference-specific-item-in-json-array)

Comment: Not really; from the URL, he seems to be using some remote deployment plugin, in which case the deployed artifacts won't be listed as artifacts by the API.

Answer (score 6):

you mean this?

```
http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=artifacts[*]
```

Reference: 
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236710/jenkins-rest-api-using-tree-to-reference-specific-item-in-json-array)

Comment: Not really; from the URL, he seems to be using some remote deployment plugin, in which case the deployed artifacts won't be listed as artifacts by the API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [ArtifactDeployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin), then, unfortunately, the artifacts deployed through it won't be listed by the API.

The ideal solution, if you have the time for it, would be to mod the plugin and add an API to it.

In my case, due to time constraints, I had to scrape the page instead, by fetching the build's HTML page and picking up all the `<a>` tags whose `href` started with "deployedartifact/downloads".