# Jenkins Rest API get the commits of a particular build

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm trying to get the commits list of a particular build in jenkins. However Jenkins Rest API documentation does not provide any comprehensive details about how to get this done.

Any help?.. suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

did you try this?

For `changeSet`, you can use `http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=changeSet[*[*]]` to retrieve everything. Use nested square braces for specific sub-subproperties, e.g. `http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=changeSet[items[revision]]`

reference : 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236710/jenkins-rest-api-using-tree-to-reference-specific-item-in-json-array)

Answer (score 1):

**changeSet** keyword seems to be working fine with Perforce. But for git there is a minor change. It is **changeSets**.
So for git it would be `http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=changeSets[*[*]]`

Comment: Do you know from which version of jenkins this changes has been added?