# Jenkins - Save last build changes to a text file

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server with a job that has git SCM. I want to be able to save the changes (comments+author) of every build to a different **text file**. Please don't tell me to scrape a html file. There must be an elegant way.

Comment: Is that a pipeline build?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jenkins REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to retrieve the list of builds for a job with details about each build. In the example URL below, I've used the [*tree* parameter to limit the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17236710/172599), but you may want to retrieve more information about each build:

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/api/json?pretty=true&tree=builds[id,changeSet[items[author,msg]]]
```

There's some documentation of the API within Jenkins, each page has a *REST API* link at the bottom with generic syntax and content-specific documentation.

You can use your favorite scripting language to both retrieve the information from the Jenkins API and parse the JSON and create text files in whatever format you need.

Comment: But Dave, is this data available at the post build step?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you were trying to perform this as part of the build.

Comment: Oh, so I will fix my question.