# Jenkinsfile - get all changes between builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236710/jenkins-rest-api-using-tree-to-reference-specific-item-in-json-array) is there a way to get the equivalent information from when using the mult-branch pipeline? Specifically - the list of commits since the last successful build.

Currently we use the following

```
def scmAction = build?.actions.find { action -> 
    action instanceof jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction
}
return scmAction?.revision?.hash
```

but this only returns the last commit that triggered the build if multiple commits were pushed. I accept that the very first build of a new branch might be ambiguious but getting a list of commits that triggered the build *when possible* would be very useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found a solution that seems to work for us. It revolves around getting the `currentBuild` commit hash and then the `lastSuccessfulBuild` commit hash. First we wrote a utility method for getting a commit hash of a given Jenkins build object:

```
def commitHashForBuild(build) {
  def scmAction = build?.actions.find { action -> action instanceof jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction }
  return scmAction?.revision?.hash
}
```

then use that to get the `lastSuccessfulBuild`'s hash:

```
def getLastSuccessfulCommit() {
  def lastSuccessfulHash = null
  def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
  if ( lastSuccessfulBuild ) {
    lastSuccessfulHash = commitHashForBuild(lastSuccessfulBuild)
  }
  return lastSuccessfulHash
}
```

finally combine those two in a `sh` function to get the list of commits

```
  def lastSuccessfulCommit = getLastSuccessfulCommit()
  def currentCommit = commitHashForBuild(currentBuild.rawBuild)
  if (lastSuccessfulCommit) {
    commits = sh(
      script: "git rev-list $currentCommit \"^$lastSuccessfulCommit\"",
      returnStdout: true
    ).split('\n')
    println "Commits are: $commits"
  }
```

you can then use the `commits` array to query various things in Git as your build requires. E.g. you can use this data to get a list of all changed files since the last successful build.

I have put this into a complete [example Jenkinsfile](https://gist.github.com/ftclausen/8c46195ee56e48e4d01cbfab19c41fc0) Gist to show how it fits together in context.

A possible improvement would be to use a Java/Groovy native Git library instead of shelling out to a `sh` step.

Comment: Hi @Fred, i tried your solution but doesn't work. i have granted the script to access currentBuild.rawBuild, but it `lastSuccessfulCommit` still return null. Is there any configuration that I miss?

Comment: @AgungPratama if you’ve never had a successful build or this is the first build then lastSuccessfulCommit will be null.

Comment: how can we proceed in case of first build, if the build has multiple commit? and get all the files changes on those commits

Comment: For the first build this situation is not applicable since we want changes between two builds. For the first build we’d not do anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think Jenkins Last changes plugin can provide the information you need, take a look here:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/last-changes, following is an example:

```
node {
      stage("checkout") {
        git url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin.git'
      }

      stage("last-changes") {
        def publisher = LastChanges.getLastChangesPublisher "LAST_SUCCESSFUL_BUILD", "SIDE", "LINE", true, true, "", "", "", "", ""
              publisher.publishLastChanges()
              def changes = publisher.getLastChanges()
              println(changes.getEscapedDiff())
              for (commit in changes.getCommits()) {
                  println(commit)
                  def commitInfo = commit.getCommitInfo()
                  println(commitInfo)
                  println(commitInfo.getCommitMessage())
                  println(commit.getChanges())
              }
      }

}
```

Note that by default (without the need for groovy scripting) the plugin makes the list of commits available for browsing on the jenkins UI, [see here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin/master/images/commits.png).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Great plugin, I would use it if it worked with submodules. I've rolled my own leveraging ```sh 'git log -p --submodule=diff ${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}..${GIT_COMMIT} > CHANGELOG.txt'
sh 'diff2html --style side -i file -F CHANGELOG.html -- CHANGELOG.txt'
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'CHANGELOG*'```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin/issues/64

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for how to get the git hash of the last successful build to do some git diff-tree change detection. I was following Friedrich's answer to programmatically get the SCM actions and revision hash out of the build returned from currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild().

I was struggling to get this working with the current Jenkins API, and then realized that the git Jenkins plugin now exports the env var GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT. I now just refer to ${env.GIT_COMMIT} and ${env.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT} to do a git diff-tree in my pipelines.