# Jenkins Pipeline throwing java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun even with @NonCPS

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The code is fairly simple I just want a rev-list to post to slack. But the part that is causing me the issue is when I am actually trying to get the rev-list from git.

Problem Code

```
@NonCPS
def getRevisionList(currentCommit, lastSuccessfulCommit) {
     def commits = sh(
        script: "git rev-list $currentCommit $lastSuccessfulCommit",
        returnStdout: true
    ).split('\n')
    echo "$commits"
}
```

Complete Code:

```html
pipeline {
    environment {
      failureMessage = ""
    }

  agent {
        node {
            label 'gsacsp-build02.reisys.com'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Parse Commits') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def currentBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild
                    def currentCommit = commitHashForBuild(currentBuild)
                    def lastSuccessfulCommit =  getLastSuccessfulCommit()

                    getRevisionList(currentCommit, lastSuccessfulCommit)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'BOT_SLACK_HOOK', variable: 'BOT_SLACK_HOOK')]) {
               script {
                    failureMessage = readFile "jenkinshelpers/slackfailuremessage.json"
                    sh "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '$failureMessage' $BOT_SLACK_HOOK"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Groovy Helper Methods

@NonCPS
def getRevisionList(currentCommit, lastSuccessfulCommit) {
     def commits = sh(
        script: "git rev-list $currentCommit $lastSuccessfulCommit",
        returnStdout: true
    ).split('\n')
    echo "$commits"
}

@NonCPS
def getLastSuccessfulCommit() {
  def lastSuccessfulHash = null
  def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
  if ( lastSuccessfulBuild ) {
    lastSuccessfulHash = commitHashForBuild( lastSuccessfulBuild )
  }
  return lastSuccessfulHash
}

@NonCPS
def commitHashForBuild(build) {
    def scmAction = build?.actions.find { action -> action instanceof jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction }
    return scmAction?.revision?.hash
}
```

The Error Jenkins is giving me is this:

```
an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@76bde0fe
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@662f031a
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@1156ea7f
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@5bada334
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@42bbb563
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@42bbb563
```

Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun

More of less I am following the below, however I am getting the error. I have tried running it the original way but am not having any luck with that either.

[Jenkinsfile - get all changes between builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334453/jenkinsfile-get-all-changes-between-builds)

Comment: That stack trace is not super useful beyond the first few lines of each error. Could you use that saved space to post the relevant part of your Jenkinsfile instead?

Comment: Good point hope this is more useful.

Comment: If you set your three `def` to `null` after the `getRevisionList` invocation, does that fix the error?

Comment: I tied adding null to the variables after the call and same results.

Comment: Per documentation (see: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin) in workflow-cps-plugin, NonCPS functions can't call any CPS functions or Jenkins steps and can't have non-serializable parameters or return values. I am not sure how `sh` and `echo` in the OP's function are even working. In my test, I couldn't get `echo` and a few `WorkflowRun` API calls to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception you see is caused by the following line:

```
def currentBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild
```

`currentBuild.rawBuild` returns a non-serializable object, thus has to be called inside a `@NonCPS` method to avoid getting this exception. Try simplifying your helper methods so they access `currentBuild` variable inside `@NonCPS`:

```
@NonCPS
def getRevisionList(currentCommit, lastSuccessfulCommit) {
     def commits = sh(
        script: "git rev-list $currentCommit $lastSuccessfulCommit",
        returnStdout: true
    ).split('\n')
    echo "$commits"
}

@NonCPS
def getLastSuccessfulCommit() {
  def lastSuccessfulHash = null
  def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
  if ( lastSuccessfulBuild ) {
    lastSuccessfulHash = commitHashForBuild( lastSuccessfulBuild )
  }
  return lastSuccessfulHash
}

@NonCPS
def commitHashForBuild() {
    def scmAction = currentBuild?.rawBuild?.actions?.find { action -> action instanceof jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction }
    return scmAction?.revision?.hash
}
```

> **currentBuild.rawBuild** - a `hudson.model.Run` with [further APIs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html), only for trusted libraries or administrator-approved scripts outside the sandbox; the value will not be `Serializable` so you may only access it inside a method marked `@NonCPS`
>
> ---
>
> *Source: [https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild](https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild_)*

Comment: I am able to call def currentBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild just fine from the steps field this issue only comes up when i add the getRevisionList. I have tried it as you suggested and i get the same error when i add the getRevisionList code back.

Comment: @Ekalbs In this case simplifying your helper methods should do the trick - access `currentBuild` variable directly inside helper methods and don't pass it as a parameter to `commitHashForBuild` method (you access this variable directly already in `getLastSuccessfullCommit` method). Something like this worked for me - https://gist.github.com/wololock/b5fc2a6281120213d5186c04927cd15c

Comment: You're were right i must have typoed something I used the file you created and it worked as expected thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks for the `currentBuild?.rawBuild?.actions` null check! Never seen that before.