# If a build failed in downstream job, how to send email to user who triggered it's upstream job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, email-ext

Upstream Job:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                build job: 'test-app', parameters: [string(name: 'dummy', value: "")]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Downstream Job:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello - downstream') {
            steps {
                try{
                sh ''
                }
                catch(e){
                emailext body: "Stage failed, Please check $BUILD_URL", subject: 'Build Failed', recipientProviders: [buildUser()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if downstream job fails, I want to send email to the user who triggered it's upstream job. `[buildUser()]` is giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out which job triggered the downstream job.

```
def upstreamJob = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)
```

Then it can be found out who triggered the upstream job

```
def upstreamJobCause = upstreamJob.getUpstreamRun().getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
```

From the `upstreamJobCause` it is possible to retrieve `User` object and then the email address of that user

```
def user = User.get(upstreamJobCause.getUserId())
def userMail = user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getEmailAddress()
println("User mail: " + userMail)
```

You can put this code into your `catch` block. Note that this code will only work for your use case, otherwise error handling is necessary (e.g. if upstream job gets time-triggered the code will not work).

[Mailer UserProperty](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/mailer/hudson/tasks/Mailer.UserProperty.html)
[Model Run](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html)
[Model User](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html)

Comment: Hi @Melkjot, I tried your code, getting exceptions: `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildUpstreamCause`

Comment: @NarasingaRao it works in my pipeline code. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638793/10721630 and try it out.