# Jenkins print build job commit IDs

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to store and print all the commits happend to git since last build in jenkins pipeline

[please find this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCnJs.png)

There are 3 commits happened to git between previous build and current build, I just need to print those commit IDs and name of the user who did that commit

Comment: Look at this answer and see if you can use this solution to get the list of commits https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384345/11543023. I you after  a diff of all the changes between builds, I would suggest the ''Last Changes' jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to get the change set between the last successful build and the current build. If you just want to get the change set from the last build you can simply do `currentBuild.changeSets` in your Pipeline.

```
def allChangeSetsFromLastSuccessfulBuild() {
    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("$JOB_NAME")
    def lastSuccessBuild = job.lastSuccessfulBuild.number as int
    def currentBuildId = "$BUILD_ID" as int
    
    def changeSets = []

    for(int i = lastSuccessBuild + 1; i < currentBuildId; i++) {
        echo "Getting Change Set for the Build ID : ${i}"
        def changeSet = job.getBuildByNumber(i).getChangeSets()
        changeSets.addAll(changeSet)
    }
    changeSets.addAll(currentBuild.changeSets) // Add the current change set
    return changeSets
}
```